# Randomly choose two values without repetition in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe `df` with `N` columns and `M` rows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))
>>> df
   a  b  c  d  e
0  4  4  5  5  7
1  9  3  8  8  1
2  2  8  1  8  5
3  9  5  1  2  7
4  3  5  8  2  3
5  2  8  8  2  8
6  3  1  7  2  6
7  4  1  5  6  3
8  5  4  4  9  5
9  3  7  5  6  6
```

I want to randomly choose two columns and then randomly choose one particular row (this would give me two values of the same row). I can achieve this using

```
>>> df.sample(2, axis=1).sample(1,axis=0)
   e  a
1  3  5
```

I want to perform this `K` times like below :

```
>>> for i in xrange(5):
...     df.sample(2, axis=1).sample(1,axis=0)
...
   e  a
1  3  5
   d  b
2  1  9
   e  b
4  8  9
   c  b
0  6  5
   e  c
1  3  5
```

**I want to ensure that I do not choose the same two values (by choosing the same two columns and same row)  in any of the trials. How would I achieve this?**

I want to then perform a bitwise XOR operation on the two chosen values in each trial as well. For example, 3 ^ 5, 1 ^ 9 , .. and count all the bit differences in the chosen values.

Comment: can you create a proper df wth a sample random expected df? with explainations, right now its not very clear

Comment: You could do a simple check with an if statement to see if value in col 1 == value in col 2 after you resampled your df. if so then pick a different sample, else do whatever you want to do with your values. Now this seems to be the "obvious" simple answer, are you looking for an answer that takes into account time complexity tradeoffs and code style (pythonic way of doing it, etc)?

Comment: Choose K random integers without replacement in the range [0, N * N - 1].

Comment: @anky_91 I have updated the question with a df and example.

Comment: @Teddy I don't want to check if the values are the same. But I want to ensure the same columns and rows are not sampled between trials. For example, I don't want    3 & 5 from Col e and Col a & row 1 to be chosen twice. But 3 & 5 from col e and col c row 1 is fine.

Comment: you can simply remove from your dataframe the rows you already chose

Comment: @PaulKovtun No, I cannot. Think of it as a 3 item tuple {Col A, Col B, row}. As long as any of them is different between trials, it is fine. If I remove the row after sampling, I lose out on potentially sampling two new columns but on the same row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a list of all of the index by 2 column tuples. And then take random selections from that without replacement.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations, product

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 10, (10, 5)), columns=list('abcde'))
#df = df.reset_index() #if index contains duplicates
```

#### Code

```
K = 5
choices = np.array(list(product(df.index, combinations(df.columns, 2))))
idx = choices[np.r_[np.random.choice(len(choices), K, replace=False)]]

#array([[9, ('a', 'e')],
#       [2, ('a', 'e')],
#       [1, ('a', 'c')],
#       [3, ('b', 'e')],
#       [8, ('d', 'e')]], dtype=object)
```

Then you can decide how exactly you want your output, but something like this is close to what you show:

```
pd.concat([df.loc[myid[0], list(myid[1])].reset_index().T for myid in idx])
#       0  1
#index  a  e
#9      4  8
#index  a  e
#2      1  1
#index  a  c
#1      7  1
#index  b  e
#3      2  3
#index  d  e
#8      5  7
```